# Countdown is not updating even with SetInterval

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jira, atlassian-forge

I am trying to create a countdown forge application that takes an input of type date and starts counting based on the actual date.
As an example, I am giving as input "After 3 days from now", But I only get as a result, 2d:23h:59m:59s , ans this result is not updating every second.

Here is the main function:

```
const useCountdown = (targetDate) => {
const countDownDate = new Date(targetDate).getTime();

const [countDown, setCountDown] = useState(
countDownDate - new Date().getTime()
);

useEffect(() => {
const interval = setInterval(() => {
  setCountDown(countDownDate - new Date().getTime());
}, 1000);

return () => clearInterval(interval);
}, [countDownDate]);

return getReturnValues(countDown);
};
```

This is where I display the countdown:

```
const Edit = () => {

const THREE_DAYS_IN_MS = 3 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
const NOW_IN_MS = new Date().getTime();

const dateTimeAfterThreeDays = NOW_IN_MS + THREE_DAYS_IN_MS;
 return(
  <Fragment>
  <Text>Time left 123:</Text>
  <CountdownTimer targetDate={dateTimeAfterThreeDays} />
  </Fragment>
   )
       };
    export const renderFieldView = render(<View />);
```

I am using Atlassian forge and deploying the app in Jira.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope the original poster has found the solution by now, but for anyone coming across this post, I believe part of the reason this isn't working is because it's using UI Kit (original) which uses an Atlassian implementation of useEffect that doesn't work quite the same way as React.

I've written a bit more about how Forge uses hooks in each of the different kinds of apps in this blog https://blog.developer.atlassian.com/a-deeper-look-at-hooks-in-forge/

I can confirm, if you build this using UI Kit 2 (which uses React hooks) then it will work.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35024426)

Comment: Hmm, I did say if you build the code using UI Kit 2 - which uses react hooks, then it will work (without any modification).  The reason the UI Kit 1 implementation doesn't work is not really a short answer (hence my blog) and I'm not sure whether there's a workaround to get this working easily in UI kit 1

Comment: You should include as much as possible here instead of redirecting to blog - even if onl some kind of summary of what's there. This answers lacks details currently.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you do not have an error in your console?

The only thing I can think of is using milliseconds (`Number`) as a `Date` or vice versa.

```js
const { Fragment, useEffect, useState } = React;

const shiftDate = (date) =>
  new Date(date.getTime() - date.getTimezoneOffset() * 6e4);

const startOfYearLocal = (date) =>
  shiftDate(new Date(date.getFullYear(), 0, 1));

const dayOfYear = (date) =>
  Math.floor((date - startOfYearLocal(date)) / 864e5);

const getReturnValues = (dateInMillis) => {
  const date = new Date(dateInMillis);
  return {
    days: dayOfYear(date),
    hours: date.getHours(),
    minutes: date.getMinutes(),
    seconds: date.getSeconds(),
  };
};

const useCountdown = (targetDate) => {
  const countDownDate = new Date(targetDate).getTime();
  const [countDown, setCountDown] = useState(countDownDate - Date.now());
  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() =>
      setCountDown(countDownDate - Date.now()), 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [countDownDate]);
  return getReturnValues(countDown);
};

const Text = ({ children }) => <span>{children}</span>;

const CountdownTimer = ({ targetDate }) => {
  const { days, hours, minutes, seconds } = useCountdown(new Date(targetDate));
  return (
    <div className="CountdownTimer">
      <span>Days:</span><span>{days}</span>
      <span>Hours:</span><span>{hours}</span>
      <span>Minutes:</span><span>{minutes}</span>
      <span>Seconds:</span><span>{seconds}</span>
    </div>
  );
};

const Edit = () => {
  const THREE_DAYS_IN_MS = 2592e5;
  const NOW_IN_MS = Date.now();
  const dateTimeAfterThreeDays = NOW_IN_MS + THREE_DAYS_IN_MS;
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Text>Time Left</Text>
      <CountdownTimer targetDate={dateTimeAfterThreeDays} />
    </Fragment>
  );
};

ReactDOM
  .createRoot(document.getElementById('root'))
  .render(<Edit />);
```

```css
html, body, #root {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#root {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.CountdownTimer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, auto);
  grid-column-gap: 0.5rem;
  grid-row-gap: 0.25rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.CountdownTimer span {
  text-align: right;
}

.CountdownTimer span:nth-child(odd) {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have no error in the console. I am thinking the setInterval is not compatible with Forge environment..

Comment: @mikasaacker the `setInterval` method is a native JavaScript function. I doubt that it's not compatible.